# Why does mother cat attack me if I clean kitten's pee?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

My cat attacks whoever cleans her kittens pee or pooh. Except if it was me cleaning it. Why? What does she think of this? If I cleaned it, she'd just check the clothe and it's over. It seems shes satisfied. If anyone else comes near the pee of her kittens it's war. She allows her kittens to be handled and played with though.

Answer (score 4):

female cats are very protective of their kittens and the waste the kittens make do have the smell of them so this might trigger the mothers protective instinct.

the mother trust you more than the other people around for now,but this is not positive for the kittens they need human interaction to be good house cats.

you do not say if the mother cat allows the kittens to be lifted and played with by other people,it is important for the kittens to have human interaction from the time their eyes open for them to be used to people.

Comment: This is the reason I am asking this, because she lets anyone carry the kittens and play with them, but she gets aggressive when someone cleans their wastes as if they really want to.

Comment: i am not sure why she does this,cats do strange things i do not think i will ever fully understand them.it is the mothers job to clean the kittens so mabe she dissaproves of the method used i simply do not know.

Answer (score 3):

Predators are likely to check out urine and faeces to get the smell of their prey before they start hunting. Your cat trusts you, but not anyone else, since they might be predators.